# How to pivot columns from EAV by group (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, entity-attribute-value

I have an EAV table in SQL Server and would like to pivot some of the table into columns.

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
| id  | key           | value           |
|-----|---------------|-----------------|
| 001 | Name          | Hand Protection |
| 001 | Family        | Gloves          |
| 001 | Brand         | Memphis         |
| 001 | Style         | 6030            |
| 001 | Material      | Nitrile         |
| 002 | Name          | Hand Protection |
| 002 | Family        | Gloves          |
| 002 | Brand         | Gladiator       |
| 002 | Color         | Black           |
| 002 | Size          | Large           |
| 003 | Name          | Head Protection |
| 003 | Family        | Hats            |
| 003 | Brand         | Gladiator       |
| 003 | Color         | Black           |
| 003 | Size          | Large           |
```

For each name I would like to aggregate

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
| name            | list                |
|-----------------|---------------------|
| Hand Protection | [{"attribute": "Family", "values": ["Gloves"], "count": 2},{"attribute": "Brand", "values": ["Memphis", "Gladiator"], "count": 2},{"attribute": "Style", "values": [6030], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Material", "values": ["Nitrile"], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Color", "values": ["Black"], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Size", "values": ["Large"], "count": 1} |
| Head Protection | [{"attribute": "Family", "values": ["Hats"], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Brand", "values": ["Gladiator"], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Color", "values": ["Black"], "count": 1},{"attribute": "Size", "values": ["Large"], "count": 1}
```

**SQL**

```
-- Get reference item for attributes
select distinct
[id]
into #tmp
from data..item_attributes
where [key] = 'name'
and [value] = @category

-- Get attributes for a given name
select distinct 
'attribute' = [key],
'values' = (
  select distinct
  'value' = [value]
  from data..item_attributes
  where [key] = @attribute
  for json path
),
'count' = count(*)
from data..item_attributes
where id in (select * from #tmp)

-- Make new table
update table set [list] = (
  **???***
)
where [name] = [key]
```

How can I pivot out associated keys and append them into a new column with a count?

Comment: That's not a Pivot, that's JSON. Are you using SQL Server 2016+?

Comment: Yes. It seems like a pivot to JSON...

Comment: Yes, suppose you need to normalise your data first, which'll need a pivot, and then JSON it

Comment: Are tyhe values of `[key]` limited to the data in your table? Otherwise, actually, this is going to get messy

Comment: @Larnu Yes, just keys from one table.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I mean are there *other* values of `key` other than what you';ve told of. If so, you need a dynamic pivot and that means a dynamic dynamic JSON query

Comment: If there are, I strongly suggest you normalise your data first.

Comment: Oh, yes. The keys are dynamic and different for each `name`.

Comment: Then you really need to normalise here. As much as I "enjoy" a dynamic SQL challenge, this will be "nasty", and I have no doubt that many will not be able to read, understand, and support it.

Comment: Am I not already normalizing during the `Get attributes for a given name` step?

Comment: Normalisation would be doing this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba69780638d74be3c19d4e9d74988f0b)

Answer (score 0):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8b065c69e8b4881fae35db1ed34951d)

```
SELECT   MAX(CASE YT.[key] WHEN 'Name' THEN YT.[Value] END) AS [name]
         , ( SELECT   [key] AS attribute
                      , JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                        ( SELECT   value
                          FROM     dbo.YourTable AT
                          WHERE    AT.id = YT.id AND AT.[key] = ZT.[key]
                          FOR JSON PATH), '{"value":', ''), '"}', '"')) AS [values]
                      , COUNT(*) AS [count]
             FROM     dbo.YourTable ZT
             WHERE    ZT.id = YT.id AND Zt.[key] <> 'Name'
             GROUP BY id, [key]
             FOR JSON PATH) AS list
FROM     dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.id;
```

Returns something like this

```
name            list
HandProtection  [{"attribute":"Brand","values":["Memphis"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Family","values":["Gloves"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Material","values":["Nitrile"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Style","values":["6030"],"count":1}]
HandProtection  [{"attribute":"Brand","values":["Gladiator"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Color","values":["Black","White"],"count":2},{"attribute":"Family","values":["Gloves"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Size","values":["Large"],"count":1}]
HeadProtection  [{"attribute":"Brand","values":["Gladiator"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Color","values":["Black"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Family","values":["Hats"],"count":1},{"attribute":"Size","values":["Large"],"count":1}]
```

This one turned out harder than it should have been. For instance had to use the `JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE` kludge to produce a JSON array of strings (from the JSON array of objects FOR JSON PATH insists on doing).